# Using the intermediate value theorem, can I find the smallest $c$ in which $f(c) = k$?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

Allowing that $f$ is continuous on $[a, b]$ and $f(a) < k < f(b)$, I have to show that the set $\{x \in [a, b]\, :\, f(x) ≥ k\}$ can be used to find the smallest $c$ in $[a, b]$ for which $f(c) = k$?

I know I have to use the proof of the intermediate value theorem and I know I have to use the idea of the greatest lower bound here, but I do not know how to incorporate them together.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Latex hint: `\in` produces $\in$.

Comment: Draw a picture. You should be able to see that $f(x) = k$ on the boundary of this set.

Comment: Let $c$ be the infimum of this set. The intermediate value theorem's proof tells you that $f(c) = k$, and any other $x \in [a, b]$ such that $f(x) = k$ also belongs to the set, so $c \le x$.

Answer (score 2):

Your set is both non-empty and is bounded below (e.g. by $a$). This set therefore has a greatest lower bound, $c$ say.

If $f(c)>k$, then the intermediate value theorem on $[a,c]$ gives a point with $x<c$ such that $f(x)=k$. This contradicts the definition of a greatest lower bound. So $f(c)=k$.

$c$ is then the smallest element of $[a,b]$ such that  $f(c)=k$.